# SharePoint JavaScript Desktop Notification Issue

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, notifications, sharepoint-2013

I have a really strange JavaScript issue that I haven't found any precedent for so hoping someone has seen it.

I'm working on some JavaScript code that resides in SharePoint and I'm trying to use desktop notifications for my Firefox and Chrome users.

I have the following code as just a basic test

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((window.Notification) && (Notification.permission !== "granted")) {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
      if (Notification.permission != status) Notification.permission = status;
    });
  }

  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var Notification = new Notification("This is a test");
  }
});
```

If I use this code in a custom web page outside of SharePoint it works perfectly fine.  If I load it in SharePoint though it's sporadic; some pages it will work just fine but other pages I get an error saying that Notifcation.requestPermission isn't a function.  If I do a console.log on the Notification object and Notification.permission I get different results depending on whether I'm on a working page or not working page.  On a working page I see Notification as a function with all the correct parameters and Notification.permission comes up as "granted"; the not working pages has Notification as a blank object and Notification.permission is undefined.  This happens in both SharePoint 2010 and 2013.

Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour since you overwrite the `Notification` object with your own code.

As soon as you've run `var Notification = new Notification("This is a test");` you've overwritten the native `Notification` function code with an instance of the `Notification`.

You should instead write something like (notice the lower case **n**)

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification("This is a test");
}
```

The `requestPermission` function is declared in the `Notification` prototype, which is a property of it's constructor function but **not** the instance, thus you can never call `requestPermission` on the returned object from `new Notification(...)`.

Comment: The capital N was a typo in my copying this code (its on an air gapped computer so couldn't copy and paste).  The actual code uses a lower case n in the variable name.  Besides, even if it didn't, the requestPermission call comes before the notification constructor since the constructor is only called if Notification.permission equals "granted".  This code works on some pages and works just fine outside of SharePoint.